# what is setNumClasses in LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS Spark-Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I couldn't understand what is the significance of setNumClasses here also couldn't find anything in the sparkmllib documentation.

```
new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
      .setNumClasses(10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setNumClasses` method sets the number of possible outcomes for k classes classification problem in Multinomial Logistic Regression.

In this case, it would you are setting k = 10.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the documentation

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS

```
def
setNumClasses(numClasses: Int): LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.this.type
```

Set the number of possible outcomes for k classes classification problem in Multinomial Logistic Regression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the number of distinct classes to be used for training the model, your data can assume of of these labels. The default being 2, you can also go for a greater number by specifying at the time for training, when calling .train(numClasses=3) or by calling the function you mentioned above